# No encuentro solucion. "Creating default object from empty value" Laravel 6

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-6

me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto para la gestion de una biblioteca popular y me encuentro con este mensaje de error al querer ingresar libros de mis proveedores y de esta manera aumentar mi stock individual de cada libro.

Vista

```
<div class="card card-primary card-outline">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="libros" class="">Libro</label>
                    <label for="libros">
                        <a role="button" type="button" href="{{route('libros.create')}}" title="Nuevo libro"><i
                                class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-md"></i></a>
                    </label>

                    <select class="form-control" name="libros_select_id" id="libros_select_id" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>--Seleccione un libro por favor--</option>
                        @foreach($libros as $libro)
                        <option value="{{$libro->id}}" @if(old('libro_id')==$libro->id) selected
                            @endif>{{$libro->nombre}} - {{$libro->editoriales->nombre_editorial}}</option> 
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="cantidad">Cantidad que ingresa</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control  @error('cantidad') is-invalid @enderror" id="cantidad"
                        name="cantidad_libros" value="{{ old('cantidad') }}" placeholder="Especifique la cantidad de ingreso" >
                    @error('cantidad')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <a href="#" id="addRow" class="btn btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Agregar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Script

```
<script>
$('#addRow').on('click',function(){
    addRow();
});

function addRow(){
    //Obtener los valores de los inputs
    libro_select_id = $('#libros_select_id').val() ;
    libro = $("#libros_select_id option:selected").text();
    cantidad = $("#cantidad").val();

    if(libro_select_id != null ){
        if(cantidad > 0){
                var fila = '<tr> <td><input type="hidden" name="libros_select_id[]" value="'+libro_select_id+'">'+libro+'</td>'+
                            '<td style="text-align:right;"><input type="hidden" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'">'+cantidad+' </td>'+
                            '<td style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></a></td>' +
                            '</tr>' ;

                $('tbody').append(fila) ;
                limpiar();
        }else{
            swal({
                    title: "Error",
                    text: "Ingrese una cantidad valida y mayor a 0",
                    icon: "error",
                });
        }
    }else{
        swal({
                    title: "Error",
                    text: "Seleccione un producto",
                    icon: "error",
                });
    }

}

function limpiar(){
    $("#cantidad").val("");
    $("#libro_select_id").val(null).trigger("change");

}

$('body').on('click', '.remove',function(){
    // var last=$('tbody tr').length;
    // if(last==1){
    //     alert("No es posible eliminar la ultima fila");
    // }
    // else{
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    //}

});
```

Controlador

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    
    $data = request()->validate([
        'tipo_ingresos_id'=> 'required',
        'libros_select_id.*'=> 'required',
        'proveedor_id'=> 'required',
        'cantidad.*' => 'required',
        'fecha_ingreso' => 'required|date',
        //'fecha_perdida' => 'required|date',
    ]) ;
      
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($request->cantidad); $i++){
        $ingreso_libro = new IngresoLibro();
        $ingreso_libro->tipo_ingresos_id = $request->tipo_ingresos_id;  
        $ingreso_libro->libro_id = $request->libros_select_id[$i];
        $ingreso_libro->proveedor_id = $request->proveedor_id;
        $ingreso_libro->cantidad = $request->cantidad[$i];
        $ingreso_libro->fecha_ingreso = $request->fecha_ingreso;
        //$ingreso_libro->fecha_perdida = $request->fecha_perdida;
        $ingreso_libro->save();
        
        //Update realizado en la tabla libros (se sumaron la cantidad que ingreso de este libro)
        
         $libro = Libro::find($request->libro_id);
         $cant = $request->cantidad[$i];
         $libro->stock_libro += $cant;
         $libro->update();
    }
    
    
    return redirect(route('ingreso_libros.index'))->with('success','Ingreso nuevo guardado con exito!'); 
}
```

Estoy consciente que el problema se encuentra en el update de libro que se encuentra dentro del bucle for.

Este código guarda en la base de datos cada uno de los ingresos que cargo y los puedo mostrar en mi datatable en mi vista index, pero algo guardar me salta este error y no me actualiza el stock de cada libro que ingreso.

Si podrían comentar algo estaría muy agradecido. Saludos.

Comment: Cambia ese `update()` por `save()`, el método update espera recibir un array como parámetro y, por la manera en la que haces la actualización, no lo necesitas.

Comment: Lo intente y no funciona, igual la idea del update es que, actualice la columna stock_libros en la tabla Libro. Hace un dia se encontraba sumando bien y funcionando, no logro encontrar que es lo que toque para que deje de funcionar pero si, como dije antes, ya comprobe que en esa parte del controlador se encuentra el problema.. Gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

Tú error está en esta línea, probablemente debido a que `$libro` es `null`.

```
    $libro->update();
```

El update() requiere de un array como parámetro. Lo correcto sería que, luego de asignar nuevos valores al modelo, lo guardes con `save()`. Tú código debería quedar así:

```
     $libro = Libro::findOrFail($request->libros_select_id[$i]);
     $cant = $request->cantidad[$i];
     $libro->stock_libro += $cant;
     $libro->save();
```

Si te das cuenta, al momento de pasar el id a tu modelo Libro, le pasas un parámetro del request que no existe, debes pasarle el id que usas al guardar un ingreso de libro.

Otra alternativa que te sugiero es utilizar el método `increment()`;

```
     $libro = Libro::findOrFail($request->libros_select_id[$i]);
     $cant = $request->cantidad[$i];
     $libro->increment('stock_libro', $cant);
```

Qué hace exactamente lo mismo que haces al agregar stock.